# Responsive layout with 2 floating divs

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a floating central DIV with 2 divs inside it. I would like to have the left side DIV set with a fixed width and the right hand div to be responsive. I just am unable to make it work.

I am looking for a better way to do achieve this result. My original code is below:

CSS

```
div#content {max-width: 1140px; min-width: 960px; margin:0 auto; }
div#left {width: 100px;   float: left;}
div#right {background:#F63; min-width: 860px; max-width: 1040px; float:left; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left">Left Content </div>
<div id="right">Right Content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question, it seems to address your problem: [CSS side by side div with Pixel and Percent widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336197/css-side-by-side-div-with-pixel-and-percent-widths)

They suggest to give #right a margin-left the same size as the #left div

[I made a fiddle with the changes below:](http://jsfiddle.net/pur4z/1/)

```
div#content {width: 100%; margin:0 auto; }
div#left {width: 100px;   float: left;}
div#right {background:#F63; margin-left: 100px; }
```

Does it look like what you were hoping for?

Answer (score 1):

I assume since you want responsive you do not want the bottom scroll bar to appear.

Since you want responsive you need to do the math on the with to become a %.

I took your `max-width:1140px;` as a basis and made the max-width 88% (the % value of the remainder of the 1140 after the fixed 100px was removed.

This allowed for the responsiveness. For a minimum width I applied 70% just so the area did not push below the left div (due to the `float:left;`)

here is the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pur4z/2/

CSS

```
div#content {max-width: 1140px; margin:0 auto; }
div#left {width: 100px;   float: left;}
div#right {background:#F63; min-width:70%; max-width:88%; float: left;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="left">Left Content </div>
<div id="right">Right Content </div>
</div>
```